# Questions Regarding Ubuntu Server 20.04 Setup

Tags: server, security, raid, lvm

I am setting up a new machine with **Ubuntu Server 20.04** to be used as **file-/media- server** hosting various **Docker services**. I have been using Ubuntu Server before and I am comfortable with CLI, but I have some questions related to this new setup. I am hoping some of you experts can answer or give me some input on one or more of these:

1. I will install Ubuntu Server 20.04 with **RAID 1 (mirror)** and **UEFI** on two identical SSDs. I see that many are using **LVM** though. Are there any advantages using LVM on top of RAID 1 and if so how should I configure the logical volumes?
2. I would like to keep the OS as clean and optimized as possible. Are there any default packages with Ubuntu Server that I could remove without issues seeing as I will run most of my services in  Docker containers?
3. I am not overly focused on security, but would like to harden the system where I can without too much workaround to have the system and Docker services serving their function. Any tips besides the obvious like installing and configuring UFW and setting up SSH with certs and restrictions?

Comment: Focus on one of the questions, and post the others as separate questions please.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is generally no advantage to using LVM on top of RAID...however, an exact answer depends upon your reason for using RAID.
2. Ubuntu Server is designed to be a general-purpose server that is easy to install and that you can bolt many different capabilities onto. It's not intended to be full-featured (bloated) out-of-the-box. Whether or not specific packages included with Ubuntu Server are necessary-or-bloat is a matter of opinion.
3. Ubuntu Server is designed to be a general-purpose server that has safe, sane default settings...including most "hardening" actions already baked in. Remember to keep up on basic maintenance: Occasionally check which applications are listening for connections, review your logs, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the input!

Comment: 1. My reason for using RIDE is primarily for redundancy. I was originally not thinking about using LVM, but I a saw a lot of posts where people use LVM on top of RAID and thought there might be a good reason. I see that LVM has snapshot capability for instance.
2. I guess there is little "bloatware" compared to the Desktop version, but I am thinking about things like Snap which I will most likely not use.
3. Noted

Comment: Please edit your original question instead of trying to follow-up on an already-written answer. I'm unlikely to edit this answer since the question is likely to be closed for the reason @vidarlo explained.